# dual boot setup

Tags: dual-boot

I downloaded ubuntu Windows installer and when I chose to boot into ubuntu I just get command line without any gui. I downloaded ubuntu so I obviously want the gui desktop. But I don't know why I just get a command line.

Comment: can you please give more info or if you see other error or the options that you have to the instalation. The windows installer just create a folder into windows instalations and edit de boot options for display choice for ubuntu. you can uninstall and try to reinstall again and ckeck all step

Comment: Are you able to log in? If so, try logging in (enter your username, followed by **Enter**, followed by your password followed by **Enter**). Then run `startx`. That should start an `X` session which is the window manager.

Comment: The error is "failed to set mode on [crtc:7]

Answer (score 1):

Did you use wubi to install ubuntu?
If yes, you should wait for sometime every time you boot up ubuntu.
The command line you talked about should have something like this:

(hd0,00) NTFS5: No wubildr

Now you should wait and it will open up after sometime.

Hope you found this helpful.